# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from (Working on SOAPUI bu not on my Ubuntu)

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am facing a weird problem. I am trying to consume a specific webservice, which you can see on:

https://api-hom.amil.com.br/operadora/tiss/LoteGuias/soap/v30301?wsdl

Through the soap client I can consume and receive result properly.

But, when I am consuming through my PHP code I got "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https://api-hom.amil.com.br/ssg/wsdl/tissWebServicesV3_03_01.xsd?serviceoid=477f074ec66fee8e74f533c102c312ff&servdocoid=477f074ec66fee8e74f533c102c31348'" error

My code is below:

```
    public function webservice_request($soap_request, $partner) {
    
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'trace' => 1,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'exceptions'=> true,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
        )
    ));

    // Transformando em Array
    $json = \GuzzleHttp\json_encode($soap_request);
    $xml = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($json);

    $client = null;

    try
    {

        $client = new \SoapClient($partner->webservice_url, array('trace' => true, 'stream_context' => $context));

        $result = $client->__call('tissLoteGuias_Operation', array($xml));

        return $this->check_response($result, 'NORMAL', $client);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        if (isset($client) == false) {

            return $this->check_response($e, 'WSDL_ERROR', null);

        } else {

            return $this->check_response($e, 'FAULT', $client);

        }

    }

}
```

Observations:

[1] The problem happens on line:

```
 $client = new \SoapClient($partner->webservice_url, array('trace' => true, 'stream_context' => $context));
```

[2] when I execute the same code on my Macbook it works, but in my Ubuntu server and Ubuntu Desktop it isn't working.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: got this to work?